How to set up a new C++ project in VSCode?
I have been following a lot of tutorials for c++ in vscode, and recently I decided that I would like to create my own project. However, the tutorials I have been following contain multiple different files that I can't find a way to reproduce on my own. Those files are:
A .vscode folder containing .gitkeep, c_cpp_properties.json, launch.json, settings.json, and tasks.json`.
A lib folder containing libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and libstdc++6.dll.
The files .gitattributes, .gitignore, cmd.lnk, main.code-workspace, Makefile, preview.jpg, and README.md.
I downloaded the starter template files for each tutorial from Github, so are any of those files specific to when you upload the code to Github when you allow others to download and use it?
I tried looking up tutorials on how to do this, but none of them answered my questions.
Is there a certain way to set up the code like this in vscode? Do I even need half the stuff listed to create my own, privately owned and used program?

I have been following a lot of tutorials for c++ in vscode This is your mistake. A correct way is using Visual Studio Community.

Install CMake, C++ and CMake extensions, add source/include files, write CMakeLists.txt and you're all set

For VSCode you should start with the official tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw After you get comfortable with the official build method and using pacman to install your open source libraries you can try using CMake for your project and the CMakeTools extension

Do I even need half the stuff listed to create my own Not really. You don't need the lib if you follow the official instructions. The 2 .git* files are if you use git for version control.

The .vscode folder and 3 json files c_cpp_properties.json, tasks.json and launch.json are all explained in the VSCode MinGW documentation I linked in an earlier comment.

I would start from nothing (except one cpp file) and create everything else as you find that you need it. And don't go to tutorials, you have no way of knowing if they are good, or even competant. Go to official documentation (links above).

And to echo what was said earlier, Visual Studio Community Edition is a lot easier for beginners to navigate than VSCode.

So here is my setup:

I have Visual Studio Community Edition (with C/C++ toolset installed).
VSCode with C/C++ extension by Microsoft installed.

Now, here is how I run:

First open Developer Command Prompt (search it in applications it should be installed alongside with Visual Studio).
In that cmd change the directory to where you want to create the cpp file.
Now, run the command code .
You will see VSCode Window opens.
Create a new cpp file. Write the code in it.
Now, press ctrl + shift + B which will ask you to choose from given build tasks.
Select C/C++: cl.exe build active file from the menu that appears on the top.
Now you can see that an your_file_name.exe has been generated.
Simply run through terminal or double click on that from windows file explorer.


Thank you so much #Akhand Pratap Tiwari, that worked well. However, is there a good way to include Raylib in that setup?

@JaxonHolcomb We can add any library we want but then we have to manually configure the include path and linking settings arguments in tasks.json file (this file is automatically generated on first run). For MSVC we use /I for include path, /MACHINE for architecture and /LIBPATH for library or dll path settings.
